# Girlfriend's / future wife's modesty issue

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, hijab, modesty

Thank you for your answers. It was very interesting and helpful.

I wish you all the best in your lives.

Comment: Masha Allah, it's very nice that you are even thinking about it bro. I will pray for you.

Comment: Is there possible that you marry in your family? I believe that if you look around you in your family you will find a very nice, islamic partner.

Even though I was involved in such issue, but due to arrange marriage, now I am very happy, now my partner obeys Allah and therefore every day, every moment I feel more love for her. So, trust your parents and ask them to find a religious girl having latest education as well

Answer (score 1):

I pray Allah SWT guides you. Remember that there is no pleasing the creation of Allah when the Creator is displeased.

Please note that is it **prohibited** for a man to act so freely with a woman who is not lawful for him (not married to him nor a mahram).

Additionally, one should strive to seek the forgiveness of Allah SWT and do everything in his life according to what pleases his Lord.

Jarir b. 'Abdullah reported:
I asked Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) about the sudden glance (that is cast) on the face (of a non-Mahram). He commanded me that I should turn away my eyes.
(Sahih Muslim)

I think the following fatwa has the answer to your question:

[Should he marry a girl who insists on going out wearing adornment (tabarruj) even though her character is good?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/70402)

Additionally, know that Allah SWT is the Most Forgiving but this is not a free ticket to sin as a part of Tawbah (repentance) is deep remorse and regret.

Comment: Alhamdulillah very nice answer. please look into my comment in the question and tell me if I am right? @Naziha

Answer (score 0):

From Sister Naziha Answer, I am posting the link material here for more understanding.

---

Praise be to Allaah.

Firstly:

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) encouraged us to marry women who are religiously committed. He said: “Women may be married for four things: their wealth, their lineage, their beauty and their religious commitment. Choose the one who is religiously-committed, may your hands be rubbed with dust (i.e., may your prosper).” Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5090; Muslim, 1466.

And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “This world is transient comforts, and the best of the comforts of this world is a righteous woman.” Narrated by Muslim, 1467. Whoever fails to find a righteous wife misses out on the best of the comforts of this world, one that is better than wealth, children and status, etc.

This should motivate the Muslim to seek a wife who is religiously committed and of good character, and to give such a woman precedence over all others, and not to be heedless about the best of the comforts of this world.

A righteous woman is the one who pays attention to the rights of Allaah and the rights of other people, and the person who has the greatest rights over her is her husband.

Persisting in sin is worse than the sin itself, because it is indicative of weakness of faith and failure to respect Allaah, and it means that the person is careless about things that may be detrimental to his religious commitment.

Secondly:

As well as being an act of disobedience and sin, going out wearing one’s adornment is also indicative of a woman’s bad attitude and lack of modesty. How can a chaste and modest woman be content to have people look at her and enjoy her beauty?

But because of her weakness of faith and the strength of her whims and desires, the woman who goes out wearing her adornment does not realize how bad her action is, as Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning):

“and Shaytaan (Satan) made fair‑seeming to them that which they used to do”

[al-An’aam 6:43]

Many of those who used to go out wearing their adornment, when Allaah blesses them with guidance, become appalled at their former immodest ways.

There are well known reports which warn against tabarruj (wanton display of one's beauty and adornments), such as the words of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him): “There are two types of the people of Hell whom I have not seen: people with whips like the tails of cattle, with which they strike the people, and women who are clothed yet naked, walking with an enticing gait, with something on their heads that looks like the humps of camels, leaning to one side. They will never enter Paradise or even smell its fragrance, although its fragrance can be detected from such and such a distance.” Narrated by Muslim, 2128.

And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Any woman who perfumes herself then passes by the people so that they can smell her fragrance is an adulteress.” Narrated by Abu Dawood, 4173; al-Tirmidhi, 2786; al-Nasaa’i, 5126; classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Nasaa’i.

If this sin is repeated, it creates a black spot on the heart, until the whole heart is blackened, as the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “If the believer commits a sin, a black spot appears on his heart. If he repents, gives it up and seeks forgiveness, his heart is cleansed, but if he does more then (that spot) increases until it covers his heart. That is the raan (covering of sin) which Allaah mentioned in the Qur’aan:

“Nay! But on their hearts is the Raan (covering of sins and evil deeds) which they used to earn”

[al-Mutaffifeen 83:14]

Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 3334; Ibn Maajah, 4244; classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.

You should note that marriage to a woman who persists in going out wearing her adornment can only mean one of two things:

1 – That the husband has given in to her, and is keeping quiet about her evil action, so he will carry a burden of major sin in the Hereafter and shame in this world, for he is a shepherd who is responsible for his flock.

How can a wise man accept to walk with his wife in the street when she is showing her adornment, and the men around him are looking at her and enjoying the view?!

2 – That he will stay with her in a state of conflict and fighting and disagreement. This may be a cause of distress and anguish which no wise man would accept. So err on the side of caution, for there is nothing like being on the safe side. Look for a wife who is religiously committed, for a righteous woman will be good for you, praise be to Allaah. A righteous woman is the best of the comforts of this world; she will help you to obey Allaah, remind you of what is right and proper, guard herself and her husband’s wealth, and raise righteous children for him who will worship Allaah.

We ask Allaah to guide you and give you strength.

And Allaah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Wa alaikumselam,

To begin with, why do you want to marry firstly?

- To do sex in halal way?
- To do progress your life more flexible?
- To have money? if she or her family is rich?

Or

- To be an intermediary of children, given birth for the sake of
  ALLAH(s.w.t.) and for the properness of Ummah of Muhammad(pbuh) ?
  **She will be a mother,** you will be a father.

If your first criteria is the last one go on reading, otherwise don’t waste your time to read.

Brother, there are some vital points to be concerned and pondered literally carefully toward marriage though most Muslims(at least they called theirselves as Muslim) don’t heed the points.

You shouldn’t keep advices of those saying that C’mon, the girl will have danced to your tune by the mid of the marriage.

You **must** satisfy yourself,at least, concerning the following rules. No exemption can be tolerated.

- The first of which is Namaz(salah), 5 times in a day. **If you don’t perform it, 5 times in a day, YOU CANNOT EXPECT A GIRL WHO HAS THE FOLLOWING FEATURES**, including this one.
- Fasting
- Talking to **any** other boys(namahram) without you or your
  surveillance. (why does the girl need to talk to another? what can he
  do anything else than you can?)
- Hijab (no exemption too) ( if you don’t look at other girls , don’t lie yourself, your most important wish from is that from your future wife )
- Whenever you wish you should access her mobile phone, laptop etc. **She can do same things to you of course**

If she accepts the followed criteria, fall on the girl. You don’t need to think too much. She will be tune in with you inshaALLAH.  No worry.